# In a post method, how to get compact parameters instead of all the object properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

Maybe the title is not so explicitly. Let me explain you my situation

I've got a get and post method in my controller. In the GET method, gets the entities from the database context

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RecheckAssignment(short id)
    {
        var assignment = db.Assignments.Find(id);
        Session["QuestionList"] = QuestionRepositoryManager.GetAllPossibleQuestionsFromJson(assignment.Content);  // it's a list!

        return View(Session["QuestionList"]);
    }
```

Assignment entity contains as 10 properties. When I show this entities in the model, it shows uses all the properties, but when the user does post should get only two properties from it (Id string, Changed bool) in the POST METHOD.

I do not what to put inside of the method parameters.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RecheckAssignment(...)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I put everything in a session variable because later I must have to get the entities again, I guess this is a good option using Session but I'm not sure.

So, what should I have to write inside of the method to get only the Id and Changed properties to updated the entities.

Comment: First, which version of MVC are you using, I asked because you tagged your question with all version. Secondly, when you said "when the user does post should get only two properties from it" does it mean you expect the user to only change those two fields? Even the `Id`?

Comment: I'm using MVC 4. I mean in the view I display all the properties in the view, and I set all the properties on it in a hidden field. But I'm just interested in getting two properties on it. I guess if I set as hidden field all the properties in the view, this is a bad practice to get only two interested properties

Comment: Use a viewmodel to pull out all the fields you need for "viewing" and "posting". You don't need to put the fields in a hidden field if you not going to user for either "viewing" or "posting". You can edit your post and include your entity so we can give you an answer that is closest to your problem, if not the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ASP.NET MVC maps a `<form>` back to the Action during a `POST` it will fill in what it can. Consider a class like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

and now consider this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Make)
}
```

and now consider this Action:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(Car model)
{
    // the values of Car will look like this
    model.Make   // this will be what was in the text box
    model.Model  // this will be null
    model.Year   // this will be 0
}
```

and take note that `null` and `0` are the default values for those types. So, if I wanted to `POST` the property `Model` I need to get it in the form. I can do that with `@Html.TextBoxFor`, but what if I don't want the user to see it? Well, I can do that too:

```
Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Model);
```

and so now when the form is `POST`ed it will populate the `Model` with the value it was downloaded with. So, just make sure that all the properties you need are **in the form in some way.**

Comment: I see, so it's not a bad practice use only a few properties in the model right?

Comment: @DarfZon, not at all. In fact, the models that are used for the view should only house the properties necessary to display the data and perform actions against the database. And it's also not bad practice to build these view models -it's what you want to do so that the `POST` action can house one parameter and MVC will do the rest.

Comment: @DarfZon, that's correct, those fields need to be in the form. One note about lists though -you need to name the controls a bit differently. You need to preface them with an index -so the name's of the controls would need to be statically set to something like `[0].Make`, `[1].Make` and those `[0]` are literal. It's an index. It tells MVC that it needs to build a listing.

Comment: Another doubt, the way which I'm using the session variable is right? When he does a post, I should find the entity by id in the session, to update the database

Comment: @DarfZon, yes the code to recover the data from the database is perfectly fine and common practice.